# quotation mark after the character string

Tags: c#

I am getting incorrect syntax error

sYNTAX ERROR Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' AND ID=''.'

Comment: You have serious sql injection issues. All of your problems will resolve if you use sql parameters

Comment: And today you learn about SQL Injection thanks to someone with the name `O'Neil`. Now you need to go and read about parameters. **don't** think you can solve this by escaping quote characters or removing them.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: [This is meant](https://i.imgur.com/QD2XFkY.jpg) ;)

Comment: @SAM Why have you removed almost all text of your question? Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters, basically. They solve problems with quotes and other special symbols, SQL injection problems, and a range of i18n/l10n problems. They're also more efficient due to query plan reuse.

Now, ADO.NET doesn't make it trivial to add parameters, so that's where tools like "Dapper" come in. You also probably want to use a "reader" rather than `ExecuteScalar`, which can only read one column and one row, but that's a separate issue.

If we did this with "Dapper":

```cs
int x = (int)connselect.ExecuteScalar(@"
SELECT * FROM PrintedCards 
WHERE Card_Id=@cardId AND Name=@name
-- etc, only 2 shown here
", new { cardId = r["Card_Id"], name = r["Name"] } // <== the parameters
);
```

If you *actually* intended to read *objects*, this would be `.Query<T>` (for some `T`) rather than `.ExecuteScalar`

Comment: why new { cardId = r["Card_Id"], name = r["Name"] } // <== the parameters
); ??

Comment: @PAA because that's how we *tell the query what values to use for the parameters*; Dapper can do this using anonymous types, which makes expressing typed + named data trivial; it will add a parameter `@cardId` with the value from `r["Card_Id"]`, and a parameter `@name` with the value from `r["Name"]`

Comment: Giving me an error if i Put this inplace of the code i provided. Says ExecuteScalar is missing a reference

Comment: How can I do this without dapper?

Comment: @PAA `cmdselect.Parameters.Add(...)` - it is very verbose and tedious, but it works

Comment: @PAA you're going to have to read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1 - the fact that it takes a lot of reading to get right is *why Dapper exists!*